# combining django-authtools and django-allauth in a Django project

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-custom-user

I am having a Django (1.8) project with allauth integrated. Now I would like to have a custom user model instead of the auth.user one (which I am aware is configurable, but I need more flexibility). When I follow the django-authtools installation instruction one step is to add following line to the url-patterns, see
https://django-authtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#installation

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('authtools.urls')),
```

However this URL pattern is already taken by the allauth app (in line the instructions thereof, see
http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html
):

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter on what URL will you include that additional patterns, you can change URL both for allauth and authtools, because that URL is not hardcoded anywhere, it will be reversed automatically by those apps when needed. So you can for example use:

```
url(r'^auth/', include('authtools.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

You can also include both pattern groups on one url prefix, but if there is conflict (for example both allauth and authtools registers `accounts/login/' URL), django will serve view for first entry in urlconf.